# Get parsed PHP file

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the contents of a PHP file after it is parsed, and then store it in a variable.
I couldn't get any useful information via Google, except for this one example:

```
ob_start();
include $file;
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

But this returns the contents as plain text, i.e.: The `<?php` and `?>` tags are still there, and all code between the tags isn't parsed.

So I wanted to know, how can I do this properly?

---

**update:**
This is content of the file which is being included:

```
Testcontent

<?php echo 'This should be parsed, right?'; ?>
```

Comment: What you show should work - the code should get executed in the context of the current script. Can you show an example of what the included file contains?

Comment: And when you say you want to "get the contents of a PHP file", what exactly do you mean?  `include()` will *execute* a PHP file, but are you asking about reading it as if it were a text file?  More details on what you're actually trying to achieve would let us help you better.  You want help to find a solution to your problem, not help to make a pre-determined solution work regardless of whether it is appropriate.

Comment: Well, exactly as I say it: I want a PHP file to be parsed, and the contents to be returned, so I can put it in a variable.

Comment: Instead, you could try `$var = include 'file.php';` and in file.php do `return 'data';` (haven't tried this, but I think it should work).

Comment: Okay, but "get the contents" does not mean "parsed".  :-)

Comment: Well, I did mention "after it is parsed" in the question :/

Comment: Tyil, what if my include file looks like this: `<?php echo 'test stuff'; $foo = 'one';`. What does `$content` contain and what happens if I try to access `$foo` from the including file?

Comment: @MikeB `$content` contains the string `<?php echo 'test stuff'; $foo = 'one';`. `var_dump($foo);` in the including file returns `NULL`.

Comment: I wonder what can be a practical purpose of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tyil's last comment he wants to entirety of the php file within a variable:

> Tyil, what if my include file looks like this: `<?php echo 'test stuff'; $foo = 'one';`. What does $content contain and what happens if I try to access $foo from the including file?
>
> @MikeB $content contains the string `<?php echo 'test stuff'; $foo = 'one';. var_dump($foo);` in the including file returns NULL.

```
<?php
$file = 'include.php';
$content = file_get_contents($file);
var_dump($content); // (string) "<?php echo 'This should be parsed, right?'; $foo = 'one'; ?>"
```

include.php:

```
<?php echo 'This should be parsed, right?'; $foo = 'one'; ?>
```

Comment: That is indeed what I want. I hoped the original question would be sufficient to make that clear. But after setting the content of the included file to `<?php echo 'This should be parsed, right?'; $foo = 'one'; ?>` it still remains that string after including it.

I'm not sure anymore wether this is a fault of mine, or my webhost at this point :/

Answer (score 5):

I was using this function several years ago for a sort of a template engine, it seems to do what you need - pass a string with some PHP code inside and it will return it with PHP executed. Surprisingly, it still works :-)

```
function process_php( $str )
{
    $php_start = 0;

    $tag = '<?php';
    $endtag = '?>';

    while(is_long($php_start = strpos($str, $tag, $php_start)))
    {
        $start_pos = $php_start + strlen($tag);
        $end_pos = strpos($str, $endtag, $start_pos); //the 3rd param is to start searching from the starting tag - not to mix the ending tag of the 1st block if we want for the 2nd

        if (!$end_pos) { echo "template: php code has no ending tag!", exit; }
        $php_end = $end_pos + strlen($endtag);

        $php_code = substr($str, $start_pos, $end_pos - $start_pos);
        if( strtolower(substr($php_code, 0, 3)) == 'php' )
            $php_code = substr($php_code, 3);

        // before php code
        $part1 = substr($str, 0, $php_start);

        // here set the php output
        ob_start();
        eval($php_code);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        // after php code
        $part2 = substr($str, $php_end, strlen($str));

        $str = $part1 . $output . $part2;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: this response helped me answer another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454234/php-import-2-class-with-same-name/16462550#16462550) +1 for that.

Comment: Raises an exception if you have the last statement (or the only one) ending without a semi-colon. Example:
`<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>`
or
`<?php
echo "Hello ";
echo "World"
?>`. Both of these work fine if executed as regular PHP code.
Think somebody can fix? I made my own makeshift fix for this to just add a semi colon if it doesn't exist in the end, but would love a better fix. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify your `$file`, than use `return` in it.
Otherwise [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) it (opens a web page like browser does).

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work.  And it does for me:

```
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat file1.php 
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php

$file="file2.php";
include($file);

[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ cat file2.php 
<?php echo "This should be parsed, right?\n"; ?>
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$ ./file1.php 
This should be parsed, right?
[ghoti@pc ~/tmp]$
```

You might want to look at your included file (named in `$file`) and see if there is perhaps some strange character after the initial `<?php` that might cause it not to be interpreted as a PHP script.

To see a hex dump of what's in the file (so you can see what character actually follows `<?php` rather than what's displayed in your editor), use: `od -c filename.php | less`.

Answer (score 0):

## To do this, you have to use cURL.

### Well, if you want to do it effectively, anyhow.

I know I'm several years late, but I was also looking for a solution to this issue, and I'd like to share the solution. Keep in mind, while this script does indeed get a PHP HTML page parsed, downloading via the web protocol is very slow, at least in my tests.

```
function GetHTMLPage($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

...don't thank me. Thank David Walsh. (https://davidwalsh.name/curl-download)