# php evaluate code before getting file content

Tags: php, file, include

I have a file B590.php which is having a lot of html code and some php code (eg logged in username, details of user).

I tried using `$html = file_get_content("B590.php");`

But then `$html` will have the content of B90.php as plain text(with php code).

Is there any method where I can get the content of the file after it has been evaluated?
There seems to be many related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466936/get-parsed-php-file) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851367/how-to-execute-and-get-content-of-a-php-file-in-a-variable) but none seems to have any definite answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file_get_contents('B590.php');`, with an `s` at the end? probably a typo, but still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    function get_include_contents($filename){
      if(is_file($filename)){
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
      }
      return false;
    }

    $html = get_include_contents("/playbooks/html_pdf/B580.php");
```

This answer was originally posted on Stackoverflow

Comment: Do you have a reference to the "original" post - I found this extremely useful and would like to share the love :)

Comment: dont actually remember...but i think it was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688343/php-mailer-and-html-includes-with-php-variables

Answer (score 5):

You can use `include()` to execute the PHP file and output buffering to capture its output:

```
ob_start();
include('B590.php');
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `include` or `require` the file contents will behave as though the current executing file contained the code of that `B590.php` file, too. If what you want is the *"result"* (ie output) of that file, you could do this:

```
ob_start();
include('B590.php');
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Example:

B590.php

```
<div><?php echo 'Foobar'; ?></div>
```

current.php

```
$stuff = 'do stuff here';
echo $stuff;
include('B590.php');
```

will output:

> do stuff here
>   <div>Foobar</div>

Whereas, if current.php looks like this:

```
$stuff = 'do stuff here';
echo $stuff;
ob_start();
include('B590.php');
$html = ob_get_clean();
echo 'Some more';
echo $html;
```

The output will be:

> do stuff here
>   Some more
>   <div>Foobar</div>

Answer (score 1):

To store evaluated result into some variable, try this:

```php
ob_start();
include("B590.php");
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = 'B590.php';
$content = '';

if (php_check_syntax($filename)) {
    ob_start();
    include($filename);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    ob_end_clean();
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: *For technical reasons, this function is deprecated and removed from PHP.*

Comment: Reference for removal from PHP ("5.0.5  This function was removed from PHP. "): http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-check-syntax.php